# Creating a dataset which is the complement of a subdataset in sas

Tags: sas, dataset

I have two datasets where one is a subset of the larger one. What I want to do is to create a new dataset which is the complement of the smaller dataset. Is there a way to do this in SAS?

[The image shows a snapshot of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoPpy.png)

The smaller dataset is of specific perpetrators (In particular, perpetrator 2, 14 ,15 19) I now want a dataset which excludes these individuals

Comment: SQL joins are another option. If you look at the SQL join diagram, you want a right join http://i.imgur.com/1m55Wqo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a merge, e.g.

```
data want;
  merge large_dataset
              subset(in=subset);
  by id;
  if not(subset);
run;
```

Comment: sorry I dont quite understand that. So the large dataset is called violence, the subset is called offenders and the variable they are being sorted by perpetratorID

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL and "not in"

```
proc sql;
create table_want as
select distinct *
from violence
where perpetratorID not in (2, 14 ,15, 19)
quit;
```

if perpetratorID is not numeric, then `("2", "14" ,"15", "19")`